# SQL query to select mapping table values?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select-query

I have a table named Patient in which I have columns like

```
ID Disease1  Disease2  Disease3
         ----------
1     4        3         2
         ----------
2     2        5
         ----------    
3     6
         ----------
4     1
```

These are mapping values which I got from table Disease, in which disease names are placed like

```
1  hypertension
2  niddm
3  allergy  
4  cough
5  floo
6   vv
etc
```

Now I want sql query to select

```
ID Disease1  Disease2  Disease3
           ----------
1   cough    allergy     niddm
           ----------
2   niddm    floo
           ----------
3    vv
           ----------
4     HT
```

Please keep in mind that I have table mapped with 4,5 tables and I want original values in place of ids from all of them.

Comment: Is this already in place or are you in the process of developing the database schema? If so I would revisit your design and have a new table called PatientDisease - your current setup is a poor design which requires you to join your disease table multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

You need to join table `Disease` thrice on table `Patient` since there are three column from `Patient` that are dependent on `Disease`

```
SELECT  a.ID,
        b.Disease AS Disease1,
        c.Disease AS Disease2,
        d.Disease AS Disease3
FROM    Patient a
        LEFT JOIN Disease b
            ON a.Disease1 = b.ID
        LEFT JOIN Disease c
            ON a.Disease2 = c.ID
        LEFT JOIN Disease d
            ON a.Disease3 = d.ID
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)